# Multi-thread C# application with BindingList<T> and DataGridView

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, datagridview

I have `public static class MyGlobals` for my application wide variables and multiple threads processing and changing these variables.

```
public static class MyGlobals
{
    public static BindingList<Device> devicesList;
    public static BindingList<Device> availableList;
    public static object listLock = new object();
}
```

I have one `Timer` thread, that updates part of the list (for example `Device.status` fields) and UI thread where these lists are binded to `DataGridView` tables and some of the fields (for example `Device.description` field) can be manually edited there.

My problem is that when Timer thread wants to update Binding list content then I get `InvalidOperationException`:

```
Additional information: Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'gridView1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.
```

I use `lock(listLock)` statement around every code block where I modify `MyGlogals` lists, but I cannot control how `DataGridView` handles the lists. How to make this application thread safe?

Answer (score 1):

you cannot update the UI thread from a different thread.

you can use [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142003/cross-thread-operation-not-valid-control-accessed-from-a-thread-other-than-the) to help you solve it:
for example do

```
     foreach (Device device in MyGlobals.devicesList)
     {
        Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate {
             device.text = "newText";
        }));
     }
```

or use [background worker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx):

```
     BackgroundWorker bg = new BackgroundWorker();
     bg.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bg_DoWork);
     bg.RunWorkerAsync();
```

and in bg_DoWork:

```
  void bg_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
  {
     foreach (Device device in MyGlobals.devicesList)
     {
           device.text = "newText";
     }
  }
```

Comment: There is no way to tell DataGridView DataSource handler to use the same lock that my Timer thread uses? Performance would not be an issue.

Comment: @ainla not quite sure how to answer that... it isn't related i think. c# does not let you change UI from different thread, that's why you are getting the exception...

Comment: So one way to do it... would be to have separate BindingLists in UI thread only for DataGridView DataSource and then let UI thread to periodically synchronize its list content with MyGlobals.devicesList content using lock(MyGlobals.listLock) statement while doing it?

Comment: @ainla yes but you don't have to... the whole point of Invoke and BackgroundWorker is that you don't have to do check every 500 ticks or so if something has changed. you can just tell the UI "hey, i changed something, take it"

Comment: exception. you cant do UI ops( ie bindinglist.add ) inside doWork.  use RunWorkerCompleted  for UI ops.

Answer (score 1):

The GUI itself needs to be updated from the GUI thread (main thread). .NET provides the [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) class for just this purpose. Comms with the GUI can be done via either/or [ProgressChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.progresschanged.aspx) and [RunWorkerCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkercompleted.aspx) events, in which you can pass an object of choice (e.g. to be displayed).